# C++ Arbitrary width container

Tags: c++

I have a large lookup table that currently needs 12 bits per entry. Is there a standard class that will give me a memory efficient container for storing odd-sized data? I have about a billion items in the table, so I care more about memory efficiency than speed.

I need to be able to get the underlying data and read/write it to a file as well.

Comment: What does "arbitrary width" mean? Does every element have a different size? That's not what I understand from your first sentence. Also, is the number of elements fixed and known at compile-time, or does the container need to grow?

Comment: Are you sure you are ready to pay probably *hours* of additional processing for compact memory storage? Maybe just process the data stream-wise, keeping only a part of it in memory at any given time?

Comment: @wilhelmtell Every element has the same size. But, I might end up needing 11 or 13 bits, so I don't want a 12-bit only solution. The number of elements is fixed.

Comment: @ulidtko It takes 36 hours to build the table using 16 bits per entry. So, it doesn't bother me if it takes another hour or two.

Comment: @ulidtko: I don't think we're in a position to judge whether this would result in *hours* of additional processing.

Comment: @Nathan: The time to perform 1 billion *slightly* hairy shift/mask/bitwise-or operations (in order to pack the data efficiently) should be significantly less than an hour, let alone 36!

Comment: @Oli - a lot depends on access patterns. Cross-boundary and misaligned accesses can cost a lot for a random access pattern - and is each item accessed on average once? For sequential access, the compressed data may well be a speed win, since memory bandwidth could well be the main bottleneck - again, depending on what is being done with the data.

Comment: If you only have 13 bits, and if order is not important, I would suggest not storing them at all. Just have an array of ints of size 2^13 that hold the number of occurrences.

Comment: @tenfour "if order is not important": That's a big if. I don't think you can assume that. This feels more like a database for a chess end-game of 5 or 6 pieces, where each board is coded into an index and the resulting 12 bits code the number of moves till win with both white and black playing coded in about 6 bits each.

Comment: @Sjoerd something like that -- it's a table of distances for a (simulated) robotic arm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef unsigned short word;
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned long long int qword;

enum {
  bits_per_cell = 12, cellmask = (1<<bits_per_cell)-1,
  N_cells = 1000000,
  bufsize = (N_cells*bits_per_cell+7)/8,
};

byte* buf;

byte* Alloc( void ) {
  buf = new byte[bufsize];
  return buf;
};

// little-endian only
void put( uint i, uint c ) {
  qword x = qword(i)*bits_per_cell;
  uint  y = x&15, z = (x>>4)<<1;
  uint& a = (uint&)buf[z];
  uint mask = ~(cellmask<<y);
  a = a & mask | ((c&cellmask)<<y);
}

uint get( uint i ) {
  qword x = qword(i)*bits_per_cell;
  uint  y = x&15, z = (x>>4)<<1;
  uint& a = (uint&)buf[z];
  return (a>>y)&cellmask;
}

/* 

// bigendian/universal
void put( uint i, uint c ) {
  qword x = qword(i)*bits_per_cell;
  uint y = x&7, z = (x>>3);
  uint a = buf[z] + (buf[z+1]<<8) + (buf[z+2]<<16);
  uint mask = ~(cellmask<<y);
  a = a & mask | ((c&cellmask)<<y);
  buf[z] = byte(a); buf[z+1]=byte(a>>8); buf[z+2]=byte(a>>16);
}

uint get( uint i ) {
  qword x = qword(i)*bits_per_cell;
  uint  y = x&7, z = (x>>3);
  uint a = buf[z] + (buf[z+1]<<8) + (buf[z+2]<<16);
  return (a>>y)&cellmask;
}
*/

int main( void ) {

  if( Alloc()==0 ) return 1;

  uint i;

  for( i=0; i<N_cells; i++ ) put( i^1, i );

  for( i=0; i<N_cells; i++ ) {
    uint j = i^1, c, d; 
    c = get(j); d = i & cellmask;
    if( c!=d ) printf( "x[%08X]=%04X, not %04X\n", j,c,d );
  }

}
```

Comment: Except for the `new byte[]` line, this is C code, not C++ code. C++ code would use a `template<int bitcount>` style.

Comment: Sure, but its simpler like this, and still works. I can do that though, if anybody thinks that it matters.

Comment: I will convert this to a C++ interface, but this is the code I didn't want to write myself...I will try to post the C++ version when it's converted & tested.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Boost::dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)?  I'm not saying that it would be the be-all, end all of your dreams but it could help you with some of the characteristics you've described.  It's very similar to [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/) of the standard library, only with resizeable options.

I might not try to use it by itself to solve your problem.  Instead, I might combine it with another container class and use it in conjunction with some sort of mapping scheme.  I don't know what type of mapping as it will depend on the data and the frequency of cycles.  However, thinking more about this:

```
std::vector<std::bitset<12> > oneBillionDollars; //Austin Powers, my hero!
```

Comment: Thanks; I will have to look into it a bit more. Will a vector of bitsets actually be memory compact?

Comment: @Nathan S. Yes, it is either N bits in size, where N is the size of your 'bitset', or N+1.  Try it out with a `sizeof` on a 'bitset' object.  It's all dependent upon the implementation that your compiler is using for the standard library.

Comment: The compiler will almost certainly align each `bitset<12>` instance to a word boundary, so we're back where we started.  Incidentally, under GCC on an x86, I get `sizeof(std::bitset<12>) == 8`.  Not good!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth not really, you don't have to do 12, you could do 48, which can hold 4 items in the space of 3.

Comment: @Nathan S. Testing has shown me `std::bitset<96>` has a size of 12.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem of packing. The only idea I can get is that you'd want to find a [LCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of `N` and some power of two. Not gonna be so easy, but definitely workable.

Also, you cannot really manipulate some weird sized data, so you need to pack it into a bigger integer type. The table will contain the data packed, but the "accessor" will yield an unpacked one.

```
// General structure
template <size_t N>
class Pack
{
public:
  static size_t const Number = N;
  static size_t const Density = 0; // number of sets of N bits
  typedef char UnpackedType;       // some integral

  UnpackedType Get(size_t i) const;   // i in [0..Density)
  void Set(size_t i, UnpackedType t); // i in [0..Density)

  // arbitrary representation
};

// Example, for 12 bits
// Note: I assume that all is set, you'll have to pad...
// but for a million one or two more should not be too much of an issue I guess
// if it is, the table shall need one more data member, which is reasonnable
class Pack12
{
public:
  typedef uint16_t UnpackedType;

  static size_t const Number = 12;
  static size_t const Density = 4;

  UnpackedType get(size_t i) const;
  void set(size_t i, UnpackedType t);

private:
  uint16_t data[3];
};
```

Now we can build on that to build a generic table that'll work for any pack:

```
template <typename Pack>
class Table
{
public:
  typedef typename Pack::UnpackedType UnpackedType;

  bool empty() const;
  size_t size() const;

  UnpackedType get(size_t i) const;
  void set(size_t i, UnpackedType t);

private:
  static size_t const NumberBits = Pack::Number;
  static size_t const Density = Pack::Density;

  std::deque<Pack> data;
};

template <typename Pack>
bool Table<Pack>::empty() const { return data.empty(); }

template <typename Pack>
size_t Table<Pack>::size() const { return data.size() * Density; }

template <typename Pack>
typename Table<Pack>::UnpackedType Table<Pack>::get(size_t i) const
{
  Pack const& pack = data.at(i / Density);
  return pack.get(i % Density);
}

// Table<Pack>::set is the same
```

A more clever way would be for `Pack<N>` to be able to deduce the getters and representations... but it doesn't seem worth the effort because the `Pack` interface is minimal and `Table` can present a richer interface without asking more than that.